# flask-restplus microservice not reachable on docker container

Tags: python, docker, flask, flask-restplus

this is about a simple flask-restplus microservice with an *echo* endpoint, that can be found [here](https://github.com/jtviegas/incubator/tree/master/flaskexample)
that runs locally by default on port 5000:

```
cd $src_folder
python app.py
```

[image]

but when running in a docker container with a simple Dockerfile...

```
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
CMD [ "python", "./app.py" ]
```

...with the correct port mapping/exposing, it is not reachable for some reason:

```
    docker run -d -h $HOST --name $CONTAINER \ 
--publish $SERVER_PORT:$CONTAINER_PORT $DOCKER_HUB_IMG:$IMAGE_VERSION
```

...even if the container logs are telling that it has started correctly:

```
(venv) .../flaskexample$ docker logs flaskexample 
2017-09-17 18:23:12,505 - werkzeug - INFO -  * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
2017-09-17 18:23:12,506 - werkzeug - INFO -  * Restarting with stat
2017-09-17 18:23:13,016 - werkzeug - WARNING -  * Debugger is active!
2017-09-17 18:23:13,021 - werkzeug - INFO -  * Debugger PIN: 246-320-471
(venv) .../flaskexample$
```

...and also looking ok in *docker ps*:

```
(venv) .../flaskexample$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                          COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                                    NAMES
9d90da7ae192        kakicode/flaskexample:latest   "python ./app.py"        4 minutes ago       Up 4 minutes        0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp                                                   flaskexample
```

..but for some reason I keep getting:

[image]

...and I am running out of ideas...have to say that I am not providing the SERVER_NAME in flask-restplus configuration, as it does not make any difference, still getting the same issue, and also that every other container requiring port mapping/exposing works fine in my docker daemon.
I am running these experiment in Ubuntu 14.04.5.

...has anyone experienced anything similar with flask-restplus out there?

thanking you all in advance

Comment: what url you have configured after 127.0.0.1:5000

Comment: ... there is a swagger UI in `http://localhost:5000/api/` and one endpoint `http://localhost:5000/api/status/echo`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your issue is that you would have used something like below in your app.py

```
app.run(debug=True, port=5000)
```

or just

```
app.run()
```

What this does is listens on `127.0.0.1` by default. But for port mapping to work it has to listen on all interfaces inside the container. So you should be using

```
app.run(debug=True, port=5000, host="0.0.0.0")
```

For further reference see:

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/?highlight=run#flask.Flask.run

Comment: spot on! I was using `app.run(debug=Configuration.get("FLASK_DEBUG"))`  Thank you very much @tarun-lalwani !!!

Comment: I had to use ```FLASK_APP=app.py flask run -h 0.0.0.0``` for the port mapping to work correctly for Flask 1.0.2